# InfluxDB subquery in WHERE clause

Tags: influxdb

Having some issues wrapping my brain around this one.  I have two tables in InfluxDB 1.8.x, here's the relevant data layout

```
table a
-------------------------------------------
|time               |hostname|device_cache|
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device1 |dm-4        |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device2 |dm-4        |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device3 |dm-8        |
-------------------------------------------

table b
-----------------------------------------------------
|time               |hostname|diskiodevice|diskiola1|
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device1 |dm-0        |8        | 
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device1 |dm-4        |7        |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device3 |dm-3        |9        |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device2 |dm-2        |8        |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device3 |dm-8        |15       |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device2 |dm-4        |9        |
|6/14/2022 9:00:30PM|device3 |dm-3        |1        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

So, what I am trying to do is get all the diskiola1 values for the diskiodevices from table b that are defined as device_cache items from table a for a particular hostname entry.  Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT max("diskiola1")
FROM "table b"
WHERE hostname = 'device1'
AND
time > now() - 10m
AND
"cache_device" IN
( Select distinct("device_cache") as "cache_device" FROM "table a" WHERE hostname = 'device1')
GROUP BY time(20s)
```

My goal is to have this as a time series in a graph to show the values of diskiola1 for a given host over a period of time for only the device_cache items.  This data is given to me to work with, I really can't modify it unfortunately.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?  The error I receive is
`ERR: error parsing query: found IN, expected ;`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately InfluxQL doesn't support IN operator or for the foreseeable future (see details [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7700)). InfluxQL doesn't support JOIN operation either (see details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/spec/#explain)).

Seems your "table_a" is more like a mapping table while "table_b" is storing the time series data actually. Assuming hostname is a tag while device_cache is a field for "table a"; hostname is a tag while diskiodevice and diskiola1 are fields for "table b". You could try [enabling Flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/installation/) and try following sample codes:

```
aDistinctDeviceCache = from(bucket:"yourDatabaseName/yourRentionPolicyName")
|> range(start: 2018-05-22T23:30:00Z, stop: 2018-05-23T00:00:00Z)   // start and stop can be changed
|> filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "table a" and r.hostname == "device1" and r._field == "device_cache")
|> distinct()

bDevice1 = from(bucket:"yourDatabaseName/yourRentionPolicyName")
|> range(start: -10m)
|> filter(fn:(r) => r._measurement == "table b" and r.hostname == "device1")
|> rename(columns: {diskiodevice: "device_cache"})

maxDiskiola1ForDevice1 = 
join(tables:{aPlus:aDistinctDeviceCache, bPlus:bDevice1}, on:["hostname", "device_cache"])
|> window(every: 20s)
|> max("diskiola1")
|> yield()
```

This will first grab distinct values from "table_a" and then rename some field of "table_b" so that we can join the two tables together in the last step.

Here are some more tips to convert your [InfluxQL to Flux](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-converting-influxql-queries-flux-queries/) and convert your [subqueries](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-influxdb-tech-tips-from-subqueries-to-flux/).

Comment: I was afraid of that, even though I saw examples from Influx themselves using the IN operator.  Converting to Flux is unfortunately out of the question because I don't control all aspects of the TIG stack, and the folks that do are not even close to moving to Flux from InfluxQL.  So it looks like I may be at an impesse.

Comment: How are you running InfluxQL queries? If you are getting the results from some client including Python or Java in a programmatic way, you could get the results step by step. That is, run the subquery first and store the results into a list. Then run the filter against the list using iteration.